# How to judge a request from CDN?

Tags: html, web, cdn

In the Network panel of Chrome devtools, I can see the header of a request.
If a request come from CDN, is there a flag in header, such as `x-cache: hit`?

But sometime the request doesn't has the `x-cache` flag.So how can I judge it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using a CDN to pull content from your origin server, most often times the HTTP header **X-Cache** is displayed in the response. Although this header can also differ depending upon which CDN you are using (e.g. Cloudflare uses: **CF-Cache-Status**).

This header however won't be displayed if you are using a CDN push zone to host your files directly on the CDN's servers. However, to verify that the asset is being delivered from the CDN, you should still see a response header such as **Server: YourCDN**.

For reference, [these images](https://www.keycdn.com/support/getting-started/) show the difference between a push / pull zone.